# Can you give an example of a non-formal system?

Tags: logic, formal-languages, axioms, formal-systems

A *formal system* is defined as an abstract structure used for inferring theorems from axioms according to a set of rules (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system)).

Language, logic and mathematics are considered as formal systems. Is there any **non-trivial** non-formal system at all?

Science, economics, politics, almost anything I can imagine seems to fit into the definition of formal systems. They all rely on certain *axioms* that one could not prove. They all described by some form of *language with symbols*. In all of them we use *inference rules* to arrive conclusions and to answer specific questions.

Trivially, you can always construct some systems that are non-formal by simply discarding one of the features in the definition of a formal system. e.g. Take a piece of paper, write some finite number of definite symbols each identifying something but without any underlying inferable rule. Shape of your symbols can be considered as axioms, the symbols can form a very primitive language, but you can't derive any new theorem out of it because they are constructed without any rule. This might be an example of a non-formal system, but this is trivial. I am looking for an answer from the "real world". Can you provide any?

Comment: I'm very curious as to why you consider mathematics to be trivial.

Comment: OP isn't saying that mathematics is trivial; they're saying that mathematics is formal. They want something both nontrivial (unlike symbols with no structure, which is trivial) and informal (unlike mathematics, which is formal). At least, that's how they're looking at it.

Comment: [Euclid's *Elements*](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/elements.html)

Comment: "language with symbols" is not relevant: every calculus textbook is written in current math jargon with a lot of symbols, but it is not a *formal system*.

Answer (score 3):

Natural science is not a formal system. We use formal systems *to model* the real world. It is not the real world itself. When a formal system no longer fits to describe the world, we discard the formal system (because we cannot discard the world).

Comment: @highly ...let's not even get started on economics (let alone politics).

Comment: Yes, there are models. However, there are also some fundamental things, beyond the models, that work for the real world itself. e.g. logic (which is a formal system). Of course the fact that we do not discover any non-logical physical law does not mean there aren't any. But this is very unlikely and even if we discover something like that, we would question our logic and adapt it accordingly rather than to accept "nature do not obey logic". So I'd argue that physical laws constitute a formal system.

Comment: @highlyoscillatoryintegrand Logic? Which logic do you assume? Intuitionistic? Linear? Non-commutative? Personally I use intuitionistic logic, which is useful enough for most purposes outside mathematics.

Comment: I guess I couldn't make myself clear. I am not talking about any particular logic. What I meant is deductive reasoning. Both natural sciences and the real world obeys reasoning rules, such as consistency (A=A), causality (A->B) etc. I assume real world is governed by physics laws (along with the ones we didn't discover yet, but once we discover it becomes physics automatically). So I assume natural science (so far) constitutes some part of the reality of real world. In any case, I don't see why natural science is not a formal system. You didn't describe it in your answer.

Comment: @highlyoscillatortintegrand As I said, natural science is not **a** formal system. It consists of many, which we add and discard at will.